# Flutter Notification while in Video Call using Agora SDK

Tags: agora.io

I'm new to flutter. I'm developing an application with Video SDK. What I want to know is that, when you are in a video call and you press home button, the app runs in background, at that time I want show a notification as "you are in a video call" and when clicked need to open the app. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the state of an app and to whether the app is running in background or is inactive or has been completely destroyed we use `WidgetsBindingObserverand` we couple that with `AppLifecycleState`.

So your code will look something like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver{
  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }
  @override
  void dispose() { 
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state){
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        //App is running in the background
        break; 
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        //App is being used again 
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        //App is in foreground but inactive
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        //App view has been destroyed
        break;
    }
  }
```